# bzip2 -c versus -z

Tags: compression, bzip2, options

Wanted to check for understanding; while revisiting the topic of using dd over netcat I experimented with compressing the data with bzip2. In the man page, there's `-c` (compress or decompress to standard output) and there's `-z` (complement to `-d`: forces compression, regardless of the invocation name)

Is `-c` simply a way to force the output to standard output, and using bzip2 at invocation implying you want to compress data if you don't use `-d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `man` page:

> -d --decompress
>
> Force decompression.  bzip2, bunzip2 and bzcat are really the same program, and the decision about what actions to take is done on the basis of which name is  used.   This
>                 flag overrides that mechanism, and forces bzip2 to decompress

As this says `bzip2`, `bunzip2` and `bzcat` are really the same binaries (oddly hardlinked binaries rather than symlinks to a single `bzip2` binary on my system). When the program is run it will check the name it was executed under and act appropriately. `bzip2` will compress by default, but `-d` will make it decompress. `bunzip2` will decompress by default but `-z` will make it compress. `bzcat` will decompress to `stdout` by default while the other invocations require the `-c` option to output to `stdout` rather than a file.

**Is -c simply a way to force the output to standard output, and using bzip2 at invocation implying you want to compress data if you don't use -d?**

So to answer simply - yes.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually explained in the manual:

```
   -d --decompress
          Force  decompression.   bzip2,  bunzip2 and bzcat are really the
          same program, and the decision about what  actions  to  take  is
          done  on  the  basis of which name is used.  This flag overrides
          that mechanism, and forces bzip2 to decompress.
```

So, when you call `bunzip2` you are actually calling `bzip2`, the idea of the `-c` and `-d` flags is to allow you to force [de]compression no matter what name the program was called by.